# Emacs ssh connection abbreviations

Tags: ssh, emacs

When connecting to a remote server via ssh in bash I use abbreviations in ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host aaa
HostName aaa.ssh.myhost.com
User user1
```

So I can connect to aaa.ssh.myhost.com, typing:

ssh aaa

But in Emacs I can't use this abbreviations, so to connect via tramp I have to type:

```
C-x C-f
/ssh:user1@aaa.ssh.myhost.com:~
```

How can I setup the abbreviations for Emacs like those I use in bash?

Comment: That's really weird: Emacs calls `ssh` under the hood. What happens when you try to open `/ssh:aaa:`? What Emacs version are you using, on what operating system? Does it work in `emacs -q`?

Comment: @Gilles It works, when I did as you suggested. I am using Linux Slackware 14.0.

Comment: Uh, so what doesn't work then?

Comment: @Gilles Probably, I used the wrong syntax.

Comment: just use /alias: in the minibuffer

Comment: BTW, this is a perfectly valid question, why is it closed?

Comment: @philipyassin if you feel a question has been wrongly closed, please post on [meta] instead of leaving comments (which nobody is likely to see) or flagging for mod attention (this is something the community can/should deal with).

Comment: @terdon OK, will do ; Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @philipyassin by the way,  the question is closed because the OP was just using the wrong syntax. What they describe should (and does) work out of the box. So there is no actual question here, just a misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm sorry but not only do I see a question (how to use an SSH's "identity file" in Emacs's TRAMP) but I don't see any answer (substitute the protocol with the alias name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work out of the box as TRAMP just uses ssh under the hood (it works for me). It may also help to have a look at customizing the [TRAMP completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Customizing-Completion).

Answer (score 2):

I did it by entering the shortened aliases in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
<ipaddress> aaa.ssh.myhost.com aaa
```

Has the added benefit of working for all services, not just ssh and for all programs, not just emacs.

Comment: Has the disadvantages of requiring being root and not being able to specify options such as the user name.